# How can I set locale for JSP using <fmt:setLocale>?

Tags: jsp, jstl, locale, setlocale

I'm trying to set the local in JSP.

I thought I'd be able to do something like:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="${param['local']}" scope="session"/>
```

[Java's own page on the topic](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/MultilingualJSP/index.html) seem to say exactly so much.

However, when I go to execute this, I get:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pages/ResourceBundlesJSTL.jsp(11,0) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1232)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:868)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1787)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:211)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:360)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
 org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:316)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.2 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.2
```

I've also tried

```
<fmt:setLocale value="<%= param['local'] %>" scope="session"/>
```

and I get the same error.

Comment: What jstl taglib declaration do you use?

Comment: <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several possible causes. It's not directly obvious from your question which one it is. I'll mention them all here anyway.

- This can happen if your `web.xml` root declaration does not comply at least Servlet 2.4 (which implies JSP 2.0 which is when EL is supported in runtime taglibs). Since that's already several years old and you're using a Servlet 3.0 compatible servletcontainer, I'd redeclare it as Servlet 3.0.

  ```
  <web-app 
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">
  ```
- This can also happen if the `fmt` taglib declaration does not comply at least JSTL 1.1 (which is designed for JSP 2.0). Ensure that it look like as per the [TLDDOC](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html):

  ```
  <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
  ```

  (the absence of `/jsp` would indicate JSTL 1.0)
- This can also happen if you actually have an outdated JSTL version in your `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib` or `Tomcat/lib`, like JSTL 1.0 or even the legacy Jakarta one. For Tomcat 6.x or newer, it's best to pick JSTL 1.2 [here](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) (and don't forget to remove the old `standard.jar` as well!).

Comment: Cheers!  For the record, the problem was the taglib declaration.